# Is there a way to render only after only a complete input? Delaying render() - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some Controlled Component text inputs for a form:

```
<input type="text" onChange={(e) => this.props.changeBusiness(e)}/>
```

I also want to render the (above) text input in a separate component - however! It would be nice if I could render it with the COMPLETED text input to give (in my opinion), what would be a better feel.

- How might this be implemented? I assume I could have an `onBlur`
  handler that is triggered.
- Is there any way to delay the render() till only after the complete text input?

Danke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes if you want to delay a render you just need to return null in the render based on a flag. Lets say you have a state variable `inputBlurred` that you pass around as a prop to something else.

```
render() {
    if (!this.props.inputBlurred) return null;
    ... more here
}
```

You would use it like so.

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {inputBlurred: false}
    }
    handleBlur = (e) => {
        if(e.target.value){
            this.setState({inputBlurred: true});
        }
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <input onBlur={this.handleBlur} />
                <ChildComponent inputBlurred={this.state.inputBlurred} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several posibilities.

1. Create custom `Input` wrapper around `input` component, which does trigger "change" event on "complete" change - e.g. on blur. While you typing, parent component won't receive incremental `onChange` events.
2. From parent, pass `onBlur` handler to child `input` component and as soon, as `onBlur` handler is triggered, render input's value wherever you wish.